# Sanitizing Text from Word Documents

Tags: input-encodings

When I collaborate with other individuals, I generally receive text to be typeset in the form of a word document. However, it seems that there are almost always characters that, when I copy and paste - for lack of a better word, "bugger up" pdflatex.

Is there a way to *sanitize* these special characters and replace them with their plain text cognates?

`’` with `'`, double-spaces with space, and so on.

Note: I could very well be referring to an issue associated with encoding, but I don't understand that - and neither will my collaborators.

PS: No idea what tag is relevant here, so please do so appropriately should you have the ability to do so.

Comment: Have you tried inputenc with the utf8 option set?

Comment: I recommend `sed` for tasks like this because I don't think a LaTeX package can/should solve these problems and because `sed` is made for things like this.

Comment: Would that be `\inputenc[utf8]` or `\inputenc{utf8}`

Comment: I'm not looking for a magic package. I'm looking for a method. `sed` isn't particularly windows friendly, and I'd like a solution that will be able to be applied by a layman long after I'm gone.

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` bypasses the problem and the file is created - but it still pumps out a slew of errors.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Perhaps it's the other way around (`windows` isn't particularly `sed` friendly).

Comment: You're right, but let's not go there...

Comment: `sed` should work fine in cygwin. I understand the overhead involved in that though. You may want to check out the regular expressions abilities of other languages. Python works extremely well with Windows for example.

Comment: You could try to open the doc-file in OpenOffice and then use the writer2latex plugin.

Comment: Do double spaces actually matter (except for the aesthetics of the source file, of course)?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I'm not sure that they are double spaces, but something else that comes across as a double space when copy and pasted out of word. @ schmendrich I've tried that plugin, with little success.

Comment: If the file is not overly complex to begin with, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) does a reasonably good job, especially if you can combine it with [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/).  See [here](http://tinyurl.com/7dqxhdm) for some discussion.

Comment: If someone would like to summarize the answers in the comments, I would select it as "the" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A summary of the comments, in order of ease of use:

- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- Open in OpenOffice Writer, use writer2latex plugin
- Use `antiword` and then `pandoc` to convert to tex.
- Use `sed` to find replace encoded characters